# What is the difference between git pull --rebase origin master and git pull --rebase origin test?

Tags: git

I have two local branches - master and test.
I am currently working on the test branch.
Someone told me that if wanted to apply the remote changes above the remote changes, I should do

```
git pull ---rebase origin master.
```

But since I am working on the test branch, shouldn't I write

```
git pull --rebase origin test
```

Please clarify

Comment: What was unclear after reading https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull?

Comment: Maybe you could ask the person who told you the command why they told you to use `master` and not `test`?

Comment: But when I use , git pull --rebase origin master while being on the test branch , it works. I don't know why?

Comment: I recommend not to use `git pull` at all if you don't know precisely what it will do. Instead, run `git fetch` (without any arguments) first, then observe what you have got and then use `git merge` or `git rebase` appropriately.

Comment: Yes, it works, but we don't know if it does what you intended.

Comment: Any idea on why it works on the test branch even if the master branch is specified in the command?

Comment: Because there is no reason why it should not work. It's as if you wanted to paint your house white but bought red paint. You *can* use it but the result is not what you wanted.

Comment: can you explain the difference between the two commands?

Comment: One uses `master` as the *refspec* argument, the other uses `temp`. See the above linked documentation for the implications. I can't explain more right now, sorry.

Comment: One minor flaw in the paint analogy is that all we know is that you are proposing to use `rewhited` color paint instead of `white` color paint. Perhaps they are the same, and then there will be no difference. Personally I'd ditch the paint analogy entirely and just go back to the *use `git fetch`, then use rebase directly* thing and not worry about `git pull` at all.